# Phase space, Algebra of observables and Hamiltonian flow

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I read in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9406019 the following

> In classical Hamiltonian mechanics, the states are represented as points $s$ of a phase space $Γ$, and observables as elements $f$ of the algebra $A = C^∞(Γ)$ of smooth functions on $Γ$. The Hamiltonian, $H$, defines a flow $α^S_t : Γ → Γ$, for every real $t$, on the phase space, and, consequently, a one parameter group of automorphism $(α_tf)(s) = f(α^S_t s))$ of the observable algebra $A$.

This mathematical view of the Hamiltonian classical mechanics seems to be very clear, but I can't find books that explain all the Hamiltonian mechanics from this point of view. If someone has an idea about such books, I will be grateful if they suggested some to me.

Comment: Essentially this is just saying that Hamiltonian mechanics is the study of symplectic/Poisson manifolds and associated Hamiltonian vector fields. So you should be looking at books about dynamical systems and symplectic geometry.

Comment: The standard text for the symplectic picture  is *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* (Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Vol. 60) by V. I. Arnold, or parhaps *Symplectic Techniques in Physics*
by Victor Guillemin

Comment: @mikestone Thank you for these recommandations

Comment: @NDewolf I'm more interested in the physical aspect of this point of view, so I'm looking for physical resources. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Once you are at this point, the line between physics and math is very thin. Even the books recommended by mike stone (great books of course) are hard to call "physics resources".